# Does the Wacom Bamboo Pen Tablet's Pen have an Eraser?

Tags: macos, tablet, pen

I'm thinking about getting one of the cheaper Wacom tablets to start doing some "hobby"-ish digital art.

Right now I think the Bamboo tablets are the best choice, especially the Pen only one, but after reading reviews it seems like the pen with the Bamboo pen doesn't have an eraser.

Can anyone verify this?

If it doesn't include a digital eraser I would consider this an enormous downside. Does the Bamboo Pen & Touch have a pen with an eraser? If it does, I would think about it but honestly I don't want the "touch" part considering how terrible it seems to be compared to a normal trackpad.

And finally, are there any new Bamboos or something related coming out in the future? I'd like a pen-only tablet (with an eraser) that's cheap and portable and nothing seems to satisfy yet.

EDIT: The main question (the eraser one) is talking about the Bamboo Pen CTL460 http://www.wacom.com/bamboo/bamboo_pen.php

Comment: Now that I think about it, my question might be kind of off topic since it doesn't directly relate to computers.

Comment: I marked paulbeesley's answer as the answer although Paul Collins answered earlier. Their two answers combined answer the majority of my question perfectly. Paul Collins didn't mention the Pen and Touch model though, but I still upvoted him (and paulbeesley) for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch and I can verify that my pen has an eraser tip. As far as I know the Bamboo Pen model does not.

Answer (score 5):

I have the Bamboo Pen (CTL-460) and I can confirm that the pen lacks an eraser. However, the pen has two buttons on the side, and I have programmed one of them to function as an eraser. That way, instead of flipping the pen over, I can just hold the button and erase.

The Bamboo also lacks the customizable buttons on the side of the tablet, which disappointed me at first, but I've gotten around it. If you don't want Touch functionality, I recommend that you just buy the Pen model. The price difference is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What specific model of Bamboo?

a quick Google search seems to verify bamboo has an eraser, but I guess they may sell a version without a pen eraser.

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=wacom+bamboo+eraser+function&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CLOOU_QlzTIWlKo-GNKK5ye0PAAAAqgQFT9AAxuQ&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89

I had one a few years back for a short time, a Wacom Bamboo basic model, I think I used an erase function in my image editing software, not as convenient but worked for what I was doing.

You might price a pen with an eraser, see if it is cheaper going that route, or upgrading to a model that comes with one.

Comment: You have a good point about the erase function in image editing software. I just realized that.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought a Wacom Bamboo Pen (CTL-460).  The pen has two buttons on the barrel and no eraser.  There are no buttons on the tablet itself.

Answer (score 0):

I bought one (a Wacom Bamboo) years ago (so an old version) and yes it does have an "eraser", but in many cases I will just press a hardware button on the pen and have it erase when that is down.

If you really don't want touch I think it's quite easy to find an old Bamboo at a good price on ebay/amazon.

Comment: How different are the older versions of the Bamboo compared to the newer ones?

Comment: I haven't tried the new once, but I imagine that unless you're very serious about what you need it for (in which case I would go with a different model) you won't notice much difference (of course there is the touch stuff but you said earlier that you don't care much for it).

http://bit.ly/dtqS2W I think this is the pen in question by the way, and it looks to have an eraser.

Answer (score 0):

The **Bamboo Splash** does not have an eraser, but it also doesn't have the touch functions. Plus, some reviews praise the downloadable software that comes with the tablet, and the no touch function allows you to put your hand wherever you want.

The **Bamboo Create** has the eraser nub, but the touch is there, too. You could look up a way to turn it off, but I doubt there is.

So, you should decide whether not having the touch functions is more important, or having the eraser. Hope this helped :)